# how to get the field label name as a case sensitive in apex

Tags: apex

```
  public static String getFieldAPIName (String objectName, String fieldLabel)
   {
   SObjectType type = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
  Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = type.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
  for(String strField:mfields.keySet())
   {
    SObjectField fl = mfields.get(strField);
    if(fieldLabel == fl.getDescribe().getlabel())
    {
        return strField;
    }
  }
 }
```

how to fetch the field api name as a case sensitive from above code i am getting the field api name in lower case.

Comment: I don't think I'd describe what you're looking for as the "case sensitive" version of the field name. I think it'd be more appropriate to say the "mixed case" version.

Comment: This is a pretty risky method from an accuracy standpoint. It's not too uncommon for multiple fields to have the same Label but different Api names!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `strField`, the key of the fields map (which for some reason, best known to Salesforce themselves, is all lower-case), you can get the mixed-case version by using the `getName()` method from the `DescribeFieldResult` class.

I'd change `SObjectField fl = mfields.get(strField);` to `DescribeFieldResult dfr = mfields.get(strField).getDescribe();` so you don't have to call `getDescribe()` twice in your loop.

Also, `getGlobalDescribe()` is slow. Like, *really* slow. It's not likely to be a concern in this case unless this `getFieldAPIName()` method is called in a loop, but using the `Type` class and some type-casting is literally 100 times faster

```java
// This code, example "A", (the next two lines below)
Type t = type.forName(objectName);
DescribeSObjectResult dsor = (((SObject)t.newInstance()).getSObjectType()).getDescribe();

// Is quite literally 100x faster than this code, example "B" (the next line below)
DescribeSObjectResult dsor = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(myType).getDescribe();

// Controlling for the time it takes to run a bare loop...
// "A" takes 0.45 milliseconds, and 0.36 cpu time per iteration (1000 iterations)
// "B" takes 43.424 milliseconds, and 34.912 cpu time per iteration (1000 iterations)
// Time taken varies based on pod load and code caching, but the relative ratios remain the same
```